# Building a chrome plugin, how to extract javascript generated text with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to extract some text from my University's course registration page that only appears after the user interacts with it. The information is generated via javascript.

I'm new to javascript but I can easily extract stuff from the upper part of the page which does not change, however I'm struggling with the lower part of the page which changes to display the requested information.

I have tried using:
document.getElementById and a few other variations with no luck.

I installed jQuery and tried using:
var testElement = $('someID'); 
var testElement = $('#someID');

Which also didn't work. Am I on the right track or is there something obvious that I'm missing? If I had to guess I'd say there's probably something I have to update to get the newly loaded information.

EDIT:
I asked another question earlier which shows exactly what I'm trying to do.

[document.querySelector always returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43947523/document-queryselector-always-returns-null/43947642#43947642)

Comment: I'm not quite clear - are you working on the site and trying to add more JavaScript to what's already part of the page, or are you trying to write a separate JavaScript program that will extract information from the page?

Comment: I'm trying to extract information from the page.

Comment: When do you try to reference element in `document`?